# Handle POST request that is login_required

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I would like to hear people's opinions on what is the best way to handle the following situation in python flask (google app engine environment):

I have a POST request backend handler that is login protected, meaning it cannot be executed by sessions that are not authenticated. Now, login_requried decorator already routes these requests to /login page where the user can log in. I would like to still execute the post request after the user has logged in. For GET requests, I simply store the original url in the session and redirect there after the user has logged in. What are some good ways to do this for POST requests?

Here are some things I was thinking about:

1. Store the request path and other params in session and use python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) package to call the stored endpoint.
2. Have a custom map or lookup app.url_map to pinpoint a given path to a function and simply execute the function after the user has logged in. I am not sure how I would pass the form params here, but I imagine it can be done.

Both of these solutions seem like a bit of a hack to me. I imagine that this is a standard problem, but I have not been able to find an elegant solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: POST data does not survive being redirected; you'd have to save all the post data somewhere temporarily, which could be problematic (i.e. you wouldn't want to save a plaintext password).

Comment: Is this POST form driven ? If so then make the form login protected first, so that the user can't fill in the form until they login.